# Date conversion ( c#,Asp.net MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I'm trying to convert format of a DateTime on my asp.net mvc web app.

I've this code :

```
date = Request["date"].AsDateTime().ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

That code works perfectly when the Request["date"] as only one digit for the day
(like 08-03-2016) but when the date hava two digits date 
( like 15-03-2016 ),

it returns 01-01-0001... Can someone explains me why and tell me how to makeit better ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT :

More of code I'm using :

Javascript date picker for the date selection:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
    });
</script>
```

Code for format :

```
    String date = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 0, 0, 0).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

string[] formats = { "dd-MM-yyyy" };
DateTime resultDate = new DateTime();
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Request["date"], formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out resultDate))
            {
                //if everything good you will have your date in resultDate variable
                date = resultDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            }
```

Comment: Most likely because the `.AsDateTime()` extension method is parsing the data using a culture which is `MM-dd-yyyy` - does `11-03-2016` work?

Comment: Why are you reading the query parameter from the *Request* object instead of using an action parameter? Why use a localized format either instead of eg. 2015-03-15 which can be parsed unambiguously?

Comment: Where does that parameter come from? If you change it to the ISO format, you could even use a DateTime-typed parameter in your action method

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes 11-03-2016 is working

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using the request because I'm using a javascript datepicker in my view and that's where the date come from.

Comment: @MrPixel6 this doesn't affect how you *read* the parameter. If you had an action parameter called `date` it would receive the same value. Also, which DatePicker? The jQuery DatePicker returns a Date object which can be formatted to ISO using `toISOString()`, or you can get the date in ISO directly with `formatDate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.AsDateTime()` Method using your current machine culture (It depends on your application `App.Config` or `Web.Config`).

If you 100% sure that you have your date in `dd-MM-yyyy` format you can parce it like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Request["date"], "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

As Stephen Muecle mention it's better to use `DateTime.TryParseExact()` method:

```
//here you can define more that one format to parce
string[] formats = { "dd-MM-yyyy"};
DateTime resultDate = new DateTime();
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Request["date"], formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out resultDate))
{
    //if everything good you will have your date in resultDate variable
    date = resultDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
}
else
{ 
    //here the logic if parce fails
}
```

Ok as Panagiotis Kanavos menthion it's not a good idea to Hard-coding the culture. If you want to do things right you should deal with globalization.

In your `Web.Config` you should set `uiCulture` and `culture`:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
```

And then when you init your jquery ui datepicker you should set current culture. Something like this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: '@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern' });
```

If you set globalization in `Web.Config` your whoule app Culture will be sync and you will be able to use even `.AsDateTime()`.

Comment: `TryParseExact()` would be better to avoid any potential exception.

Comment: Hard-coding the date format is a bad idea. Far better to use the standard YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: @StephenMuecke actually it would be *worse*, because it would allow processing even if the date literal was invalid - unless proper handling code was uses (eg check for missing, invalid values)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, If you use `TryParseExact()` you can then test the result before using `.ToString()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos agreed that it's better to use standart formats. But if you had to localize your application you had to sync your culture in all your app and get your format from `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`.

Comment: Hum I don't enter in the if(){ in fact :s

Comment: @teovankot Not at all, and I *do* have to localize to dozens of languages. Hard-coding the culture is a bug unless there is absolutely no chance the web site will **ever** be used by a user with a different culture. Plus, it's harder to hard-code it than it is to write proper culture-agnostic code

Comment: @teovankot Thank you for your help again I finally made it !

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your help !

Comment: If you going to set the culture in the server because all dates are expected to be in that format, then all this code would be unnecessary. The POST method should just have a parameter `DateTime date` (or a model with that property) and it will all be bound correctly without the need to use `Request` (which is never necessary in MVC) or `.AsDateTime()` or `TryParseExact()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime unformattedDate;
if(DateTime.TryParse(Request["date"], out unformattedDate)
{
   DateTime formattedDate = unformattedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't that fail in exactly the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
date = (DateTime)Request["date"];
String myDate=date.ToString();
```